# Different Results Running from Eclipse and cmd? Java program--Magic Square

Tags: java, eclipse

So as the title, I've got different results running my Magic Square program from Eclipse and cmd command. The eclipse one does not make sense.

[image]
[image]

(The position of sentence "Wrong number..." should be wrong in the eclipse one)

Anyone know how to fix it? Thanks a lot!

```
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Set;
    public class MagicSquare{
    // the two-dimensional array to restore my own magic square.
    private int[][] myMagicSquare;
    private int n;


    public MagicSquare(){
    }

    /**
     * Function: this constructor takes and positive, odd integer parameter to generate a new 
     * magic square.</br>   
     * @param n the length of magic square</br>
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException for negative or even parameter. 
     * Preston Jul 5, 20151:15:40 AM</br>
     */
    public MagicSquare(int n){
        //throws runtime error.
        if(!rangeCheck(n)){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal number"); 
        }else{
            // create my magic square array with length of given integer. 
            this.n = n;
            myMagicSquare = new int[n][n];
            // generate the magic square.
            createMagicSquare();
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Function: this constructor takes a 2D array as a parameter. If the 2D array can generate
     * a magic square, then put the values into <i>my magic square</i></br>, if not then throws
     * the exception.   
     * @param newMagicSquare the tested 2D array</br>
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * Preston Jul 5, 20151:23:10 AM</br>
     */
    public MagicSquare(int[][] newMagicSquare){
        this.n = newMagicSquare.length;
        // determine whether or not the 2D array can generate a magic square.
        if(isMagic(newMagicSquare))
            myMagicSquare = newMagicSquare;
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("This is not a magic square");
    }
    /**
     * 
     * Function:Range check for the input of magic square length</br>   
     * @param n the length of magic square
     * @return true if the length is a positive, odd number</br>
     * Preston Jul 5, 20152:53:29 PM</br>
     */
    private static boolean rangeCheck(int n){
        return !((n>0&&n%2==0)||n<=0);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Function: return the magic number of the magic square.</br>  
     * @return the value magic number.</br>
     * Preston Jul 5, 20151:29:02 AM</br>
     */
    private int getMagicNumber(){
        return (n*(n*n+1))/2;   
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Function: For challenging level: check if all numbers for 1 to n*n only appeared once
     * in the given 2D array.</br>  
     * @param temp the temporary 2D array as parameter.
     * @return true if all numbers from 1 to n*n only appeared once</br>
     * Preston Jul 5, 20151:30:03 AM</br>
     */
    private static boolean noRepeatedNum(int[][] temp){
        int n = temp.length;
        // Set up the standard Set for comparison. 
        Set<Integer> standardSet = new HashSet<>();
        for(int i=1;i<=n*n;i++){
            standardSet.add(i);
        }
        // the Set made of all numbers from temp. All repeated numbers show only once in Set.
        Set<Integer> arraySet = new HashSet<>();
        for(int[] x : temp){
            for(int a : x){
                arraySet.add(a);
            }
        }
        // return if two Sets are equal.
        return arraySet.equals(standardSet);
    }
    /**
     * 
     * Function: Check if the given 2D array can consist a magic square</br>    
     * @param temp a parameter 2D array.
     * @return true if numbers in the parameter array could consist a magic square</br>
     * Preston Jul 5, 20151:36:44 AM</br>
     */
    private static boolean isMagic(int[][] temp){
        //store the return value
        boolean isMagic = true;
        int tempN = temp.length;
        int magicNumber = (tempN*(tempN*tempN+1))/2;
        // accumulator for two diagonals
        int diagonalOneSum = 0;
        int diagonalTwoSum = 0;
        // check rows and columns
        for(int i=0; i<tempN;i++){
            int rowSum = 0;
            int columnSum = 0;
            for(int j=0;j<tempN;j++){
                // single-row sum
                rowSum += temp[i][j];
                // single-column sum
                columnSum += temp[j][i];
            }
            if(rowSum!=magicNumber||columnSum!=magicNumber){
                isMagic = false;
                // return false immediately if there's inequality. Save calculations and performance.
                return isMagic;
            }
        }
        // counter for the second diagonal
        int diagonalTwoCounter = tempN-1;
        // sum of two diagonals
        for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
            diagonalOneSum += temp[i][i];
            diagonalTwoSum += temp[diagonalTwoCounter][diagonalTwoCounter];
            diagonalTwoCounter--;
        }
        if(diagonalOneSum!=magicNumber||diagonalTwoSum!=magicNumber){
            isMagic = false;
            return isMagic;
        }
        // check if there are repeated numbers in the pretty magic square already.
        return noRepeatedNum(temp);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Function: check if the position of the number in the magic square is at boundary</br>    
     * @param boundary the row OR column number of the position
     * @return true if the value of<code>boundary</code> is zero</br>
     * Preston Jul 5, 20151:53:24 PM</br>
     */
    private boolean Boundary(int boundary){
        return boundary==0;
    }
    /**
     * 
     * Function: Put numbers from 1 to n*n into my own 2D array using Siamese Method.</br>
     * Preston Jul 5, 20153:20:56 PM</br>
     */
    private void createMagicSquare(){
        // starting Row number -> middle
        int startRow = this.n/2;
        // starting Column number -> the first column
        int startColumn = 0;
        // start to put number from 2
        int startNum = 2;
        // put 1 in the starting position
        myMagicSquare[startRow][startColumn] = 1;

        while(startNum<=n*n){   
            // the positions on upper boundary
            if(Boundary(startRow)&&!Boundary(startColumn)){
                myMagicSquare[n-1][startColumn-1] = startNum;
                startRow = n-1;
                startColumn -= 1;
            }
            // the positions on left boundary
            else if(Boundary(startColumn)&&!Boundary(startRow)){
                myMagicSquare[startRow-1][n-1] = startNum;
                startRow -= 1;
                startColumn = n-1;
            }
            // upper left corner.
            else if(Boundary(startRow)&&Boundary(startColumn)){
                myMagicSquare[startRow][startColumn+1] = startNum;
                startColumn += 1;
            }
            else{
                // if the coming position is filled with number.
                if(myMagicSquare[startRow-1][startColumn-1]!=0){
                    myMagicSquare[startRow][startColumn+1] = startNum; 
                    startColumn += 1;
                }
                // general movement
                else{
                    myMagicSquare[startRow-1][startColumn-1] = startNum;
                    startRow -= 1;
                    startColumn -= 1;
                }
            }
            startNum++;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        // align my 2D array.
        return toString(myMagicSquare);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Function:align the numbers in the parameter 2D array pretty</br> 
     * @param temp the parameter 2D array.
     * @return the beautifully aligned String</br>
     * Preston Jul 5, 20153:26:15 PM</br>
     */
    public static String toString(int[][] temp){
        int largestNum = 0;
        // get the largest number in temp.
        for(int[] x : temp){
            for(int a : x){
                if(a>=largestNum)
                    largestNum = a;
            }
        }
        // how many digits does the biggest number have?
        int longestDigit = String.valueOf(largestNum*largestNum).length();
        // store the final String
        StringBuilder printOut  = new StringBuilder();
        printOut.append('\n');

        for(int[] x : temp){
            for(int a : x){
                // space between each number
                printOut.append('\t');
                // add spaces for alignment.
                for(int i=0;i<longestDigit-String.valueOf(a).length();i++){
                    printOut.append(" ");
                }
                printOut.append(String.valueOf(a));
            }
            printOut.append('\n').append('\n');
        }
        // return the big String
        return printOut.toString();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Function: the main function scans user input as the length of 2D array to make my
     * own magic square. If the <code>userInput</code> is out of range, print out the error
     * message and ask for the number again. Enter the code 0 to exit.</br> 
     * @param args</br>
     * Preston Jul 5, 20153:28:57 PM</br>
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int userInput;
        do{
            // title
            System.out.println("Enter a positive, odd number");
            System.out.print("Exit code is 0, enter 0 to quit: ");
            // user input
            userInput = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
            // if the userInput is out of range, show error message.
            if(rangeCheck(userInput)){
                MagicSquare m = new MagicSquare(userInput);
                System.out.println(m.toString());
            }else
                if(userInput==0)
                    System.out.println("The magic square is not generated. QUIT");
                else
                    System.err.println("Wrong number: Please enter a positive, odd number");
            // restart 
            System.out.println("-------------------");
        }while(userInput != 0);  // enter 0 to exit.        

    }

}
```

Comment: Enter a positive, odd number
Exit code is 0, enter 0 to quit: 2
-------------------
Enter a positive, odd number
Exit code is 0, enter 0 to quit: Wrong number: Please enter a positive, odd number

Comment: you can edit your question

Comment: 2. From cmd:Enter a positive, odd number
Exit code is 0, enter 0 to quit: 2
-------------------
Enter a positive, odd number
Exit code is 0, enter 0 to quit: Wrong number: Please enter a positive, odd number

Comment: Have you tried at both places after cleaning and re-building the class file?

Comment: I did, the results are still different.

Comment: @Preston in your comments 1.from eclipse 2.from cmd i didn't see a difference

Comment: @Preston I just simply think Its just the size of the console and stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for above issue is that  bug in handling of stdout and stderr in eclipse.[Follow this link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=32205). (Not sure whether this is fixed or not.)

I also tried to reproduce this issue, but it is occurring in some cases and in some cases output and error output is showing at correct places.

Just for check :-

You may get this issue at very first run on eclipse, so don't exit the code, try again with wrong number (i.e. 2/4/6 ...) ;you may see error and output gets correctly printed.

Comment: So when i run the program it sometimes keeps giving out wrong results...but the bug report web is saying the same thing actually, thanks again! It's good to know it's IDE problem instead of the code